# Find multi-column index in information_schema

Tags: mysql, database, information-schema

I have a table with an index comprised of three columns in a table.

Is there a way I can find this in information_schema, or will it only show me three separate indices?

Comment: Have you tried googling: http://blog.9minutesnooze.com/mysql-information-schema-indexes/ ?

Comment: Thanks, I found what I was looking for at that link.

Comment: Please post your answer below in "answers" section - it's accepted SO practice to answer own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to Radek Postolowicz for [steering me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577276/find-multi-column-index-in-information-schema#comment64544643_38577276) in the right direction:

```
SELECT 
  table_name AS `Table`,
  index_name AS `Index`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY seq_in_index) AS `Columns`
FROM information_schema.statistics 
WHERE table_schema = 'db' 
AND table_name='tbl' 
GROUP BY 1,2;
```